# dd of=/dev/sdc stopped working until reboot

Tags: linux, dd

I use `sudo dd if=file.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=1M && sync` to copy yocto iso images to a flash drive.  This usually works all the time without issue.  Today it stopped working correctly it usually takes a few minutes but it completed in a few seconds. There were no errors messages, nothing in `dmesg`, `nmon` didn't show any disk activity with `/dev/sdc`.

Plugging the flash drive in and out a few times didn't fix the issue.
I had to reboot and then it started working correctly.

I don't understand what happened or why.  Is there a way to fix the problem without reboot?

Comment: Next time it fails, please add the result of `ls -l /dev/sdc` to your question.

Comment: It's going to be hard to tell if there is a problem if there is no error messages, or if it isn't reproducable... (Maybe dd was tired... :p)

Comment: @jayooin It was very confusing.  Nothing seemed to work or cause an error.  I tried fdisk, parted, whatever I could think of that should have an effect to even erase the existing data.  I assumed that if there was error it would should up `dmesg`.  One reason I asked is because I don't know what else I should have checked.

Comment: If you plug it in a second and third time, it might be named `/dev/sdd`, `/dev/sde`, etc. Run `lsblk` next time this happens and show us the results.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I've probably done this at least 50 times over the last 3 months working with yocto images. It's never been anything other than /dev/sdc.  I did run `lsblk` and as usual there was /dev/sda, /dev/sdb/, and /dev/sdc. When the USB stick is removed then `lsblk` only shows the sda and sdb devices, no ghost devices.  It was only a problem today and hasn't happened since rebooting the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this before. Happened after performing a system update, the kernel was upgraded. Did you perform an update?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  There was some sort of update but I'm not sure what it was.